# Raspberry Pi3 with Kodi runs very very slowly

Tags: raspberry-pi, performance, kodi

My rPI3 runs very slowly with Kodi on it. I installed Kodi in March 2018 through LibreELEC. Kodi is at its latest version. Any suggestion?

1. The bootup time is fairly fast; it boots up in less than a minute which is a pleasant time for me.
2. Kodi interface is unbearable instead. Whenever I click any option it honestly takes 1 minute to load to the next page. If I need to browse for movies (I use the Midian add-on), every time I need to change a page it takes at least minute. If I select a certain movie to play the Raspberry Pi3 can take from 5 to 10 minutes, but lately it has failed to load it and freezes the complete system. 
   In the end for this reason I stopped using it.
3. The micro SD card I use is 16 GB Kingston,
   (SDC4 / 16 GB, 4 years old I suppose).
4. My source power is the official Raspberry power supply bought in March 2018.

Comment: If you want high quality answers, ask high quality questions ;-). I would like to know what is slow, bootup, Kodi interface ? Maybe you could give us some metrics, I have pi b,b+, and 3 so can have a look, too. How did you install kodi ? What type of microsd card are you using ? What powerbrick (how many amps)? Please consider making it easier for us to help you! Oh, and I have high quality microSD cards and powerbricks ;-)

Comment: Thank you @thecarpy, I honestly didnt know how to improve the question and I wanted to start somewhere, please review the edit

Comment: I forgot a few things, are you hooked-up via WIFI or ethernet ? Could you try to load a film or three onto the sd card and check if it is slow there, too ? What add-on ? If I can reproduce your issue, we know it is down to pi, if I cannot ... the interface is slow on my 2b model where I have kodi, never tried on newest ... will do tonight

Comment: Update: by playing videos on pi3, it is an overall pleasant experience. Big videos (5gb) run not so good but I can understand that. I use the Midian add-on. In order to load a page it takes 1 minute. If I load a movie it can take at least 3 minutes but lately it has fail to load it and freeze the complete system

Comment: @Alessio_110, you might also like [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) for these types of questions. RPI.SE will have a bunch of like minded folks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my current experience with a pi that I have. If the OS itself runs slow, there is really nothing you can do. I currently have OSMC running on a 2B and it is fine. Try OSMC or another version of kodi, or maybe a different version. Getting a new sd card may help, but probably won't have a huge impact. A possibility could be that it is simply slower than you expect. It is a $30 computer, so don't have very high expectations for it. I remember mine usually had a few seconds lag between operations. On another note, make sure your wifi is good if you are having trouble streaming, maybe your wifi adapter does not support very high speeds. If this doesn't help at all, you might want to say where it is being slow. Is it buffering a lot? Lagging? Crashing?

Again, this is the best answer I could think of from what you told me and from previous experience.

Comment: FWIW I'm also running OSMC/Kodi on a 2B, and it's pretty snappy. I don't get any noticeable lag really, apart from when the HDD is spinning up.